# C++ about stdio.h changing stdout

Tags: c++

C++ about stdio.h changing stdout

I have a function which prints out some data.

`//overallSummary` is a void return type function that prints data out to the console. It's works as expected.

I wanted to save to a text file, so this is I did instead

```
#include <stdio.h>

freopen("summary.txt","w",stdout);
overallSummary();
fclose(stdout);
```

I ran the code, and it worked as expected.
**However**, the console kept blinking. It looked like it was blocked. Pressing enter didn't stop it. It wasn't hanging. I just lost the control of the console. Why?

Comment: sorry typo error. i use fclose but its the same issue.

Comment: first of all.. you shouldn't use `stdio.h` if you are writing in C++. Read this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/  it may help you.

Comment: Why not just pass a FILE* to the function and write to that?  That way you can pass stdout if you want, or you can pass a handle to an actual file. (Or, perhaps pass an std::ostream.)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could always do things this easy way instead of worrying about obscure corners of the C standard library. Just rewrite your function as `void overallSummary(FILE* file);` and pass the FILE pointer you want to use to the function.

Comment: @CppLearner that tutorial has the same mistake we see again and again in this forum, `while (myfile.good()) { getline(myfile, line); ... }` is not the way to read all the lines in a file. Strange thing is the text describes the `good` method accurately, but the writer of the code doesn't seem to realise that it does't do what they think it does.

Comment: that function was originally use to cout to a console.  but i wanna make it able to write to a file call summary.txt too, i went google and saw freopen and i try it at a test.cpp file and try to cout and output, its work fine. but not at this case of mine when i use on my actual program, its just don't give me my control back.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing to a more expressive:

```
#include <iostream>    

void overallSummary(std::ostream& os); // use os instead of std::cout in overallSummary

std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("summary.txt");
if(!ofs.is_open())
  abort();
overallSummary(ofs);
ofs.close();
```

Otherwise if you just wanna write to a file, that means **redirecting std::cout**,
so call it like this:

```
./program_name > summary.txt
```

In the program writing on std::cout goes into summary.txt. Using ">>" instead of ">" appends.